# How to scatter plot one x data versus several unequal y data plots in matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, tuples

Basically I have x versus y tuple of different length. How can I plot the following in matplotlib?

```
x=[1,2,3,4]
y=([1,1.1,1.4,0.9,0.8],[2.1,2.2,2.3],[3.1,3.3],[4.4,4.5,4.3,4.22,4.2,4.1,4.4411])
plt.scatter(x,y)
```

Thank you

Comment: How do you want the data to be interpreted?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that. On a side not, I do not have a preference for any kind of solution to the question.

Comment: @gogo - As you've currently written the question, there are a near-infinite number of ways the data could be plotted.  Basically, each point is an x,y pair. How do you want the coordinates in `x` and `y` combined?  If they're not the same length, there's more than one way to do it.

Comment: @Joe, is there some other method than Anton's you would like to share? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you need to expand your `x` list to `y` dimension and then flat obtained list and put in `plt.scatter`:

```
x=[1,2,3,4]
y=([1,1.1,1.4,0.9,0.8],[2.1,2.2,2.3],[3.1,3.3],[4.4,4.5,4.3,4.22,4.2,4.1,4.4411])

w = [[x[i]] * len(y[i]) for i in range(len(y))]

In [555]: w
Out[555]: [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]]

x_to_plot = [item for sublist in w for item in sublist]
y_to_plot = [item for sublist in y for item in sublist]
plt.scatter(x_to_plot, y_to_plot)
```

[image]

*Note*: You could use `itertools.chain.from_iterable()` to make flatten lists from [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python) question which is a faster