# How to plot a scatter plot between 2 variables with imbalanced data using python?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, scatter-plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1,2,3,4,4,5]
y= [1,2,3]
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.show()
```

> ValueError: x and y must be the same size

How to obtain a plot between x & y ?

Comment: Does this question help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34731398/how-to-scatter-plot-one-x-data-versus-several-unequal-y-data-plots-in-matplotlib

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

This is an idea I got from using R. In R it usually happens where the elements are recycled. With that in mind, if such a solution is ok with you,

```
import itertools

x = [1,2,3,4,4,5]
y= [1,2,3]

g = itertools.cycle(y)

w = [next(g) for i in range(len(x))]

plt.scatter(x,w)
plt.show()
```

Otherwise, I don't know how to plot uneven numbers.